# How do you sort input in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

beginning coder here. I was trying to sort words and numbers, and it mostly work. However, when I provided input to sort, it doesn't seem to work.

I tried inserting the input as a variable and it broke the numbers down into single digits, which I did not want to do. I tried converting the input into a float and integers and it did not work. I tried

```
input1 = input() #I input in 23, 12, 45
sorted(input1)
```

And I got

```
[' ', ' ', ',', ',', '1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

I was expecting for it to sort by whole numbers without being broken down.

Comment: Please provide some code, otherwise we cannot help you. `input()` returns a string and when you loop over a string it will iterate over all the characters. To read numbers you must parse the string to and `int` or `float`.

Comment: You need to search for how to read in a list of numbers from the console in python, and also how to sort a list of numbers - then combine that knowledge. Generally you should break up problems into discrete steps and then research how to do each one.

Comment: If you don't show us the actual code you tried, then there's no way for us to point out what you did wrong.

Comment: Also show us the _actual output_ you got, and explain how that's different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: `input()` returns a single string.  So, you got back the _individual characters_ of that string, in sorted order.

Comment: If you want to separate your input into pieces, you'll have to use something like `split()`.

Comment: ```split``` works for numbers with the same digit, but I am working with different amounts of digits. I just added those numbers as an example

Comment: `split()` works on a string containing a series of things (numbers, words, whatever) separated by a common pattern (i.e. space/comma).  There is no requirement that the things all be the same length.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your input is a String, you can convert it to int and add to a list.
Then you can sort the list:

```
list =  []
x = input("write:")
x = x.replace(" ","")
y = x.split(",")
for i in y:
    if i.isnumeric():
        i = int(i)
        list.append(i)
list.sort()
print(list)
```

Comment: This doesn't sort at all...

Comment: There's no sorting here or splitting of inputted values though. How is this an answer?

Comment: It doesn't work, and it doesn't sort

Comment: Sorry I replied before he added any code so I didn't was sure what he wanted
(i improved my answer)

Comment: I got error ```TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'```

Comment: you have to remove whitespace, you can't sort a list with numbers and strings
a: give a input like "12,1,4"
b: remove whitespace with x = x.replace(" ","")